# How can I update column in one table if its primary id is in another table

Tags: mysql

If an account id exists in table_subscription, I want to set table_account.account_do_not_email = 1, else leave it alone. We are getting rid of the subscription table and just using this method.

The code I currently have works for updating the very first column it finds but not all of them..

```
UPDATE table_account a
SET account_do_not_email = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_subscription b WHERE b.account_id = a.account_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` to do this

```
update table_account a
join table_subscription b on b.account_id = a.account_id
set a.account_do_not_email = 1
```

Comment: Guess I thought you couldn't do inner joins in updates. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

If you have have that particular account_id in both tables then table_account table will be updated

```
UPDATE table_account a
INNER JOIN table_subscription ts
ON ts.account_id = a.account_id
SET account_do_not_email = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this too:

```
update table_account
set account_do_not_email = 1
where account_id in (select account_id from table_subscription)
```